# asp.net mvc jQuery $.post works but $.get doesn't

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, get

Why would `POST` work but not `GET`?  I'm not using `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]`.  I'm calling this:

```
public ActionResult GetTest(string key)
        {
            var test = new { HelpTest = key };
            return Json(test);
        }
```

And it works when I do this:

```
$.post("/Home/GetTest", { key: options.key },
                        function(helpTest) {
                            alert(helpTest.HelpTest);
                        });
```

But not this:

```
$.get("/Home/GetTest", { key: options.key },
                            function(helpTest) {
                                alert(helpTest.HelpTest);
                            });
```

Why would this be?  Using `GET` returns an `XMLHttpRequest.status` of 500. What am I confused about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because return json does not return json to get requests it is unsafe and you should avoid it but if you really want to use it use the overload of json set the property to allowget then it will work

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Thanks - what are the concerns w/ returning JSON to a GET request?

Comment: It is open to hacker attacks look at this video if you are interested in learning more about security http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/FT05